# Forward touch event from UIView, to its TableView inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I built a `SplitView` class that looks like this picture below:

[image]

As you can see the `SplitView` always have two subviews, therefore it has two properties that are `leftView` and `rightView`.

The job of the `SplitView` is to manage its subview size proportion. 
If I do a swipe gesture to the left, it will move the separator location and it changes the size of each subviews, so it will look like this:

[image]

It works perfectly until I use `UITableView` as the `leftView` and `rightView`.

This is because the `UITableView` inside it is the one which will process the touch event, not the superview (which is `SplitView`)

And because the code to intercept and respond to the touch is in `SplitView`, it doesn't do anything if the `UITableView` inside it is the one that receives the touch event.

To do this I implement `hitTest` to make the `SplitView` the responder, not the `UITableView` inside it.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    return self
}
```

Now I can get the touch event in the `SplitView` even though the user swipe on the `UITableView`.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        self.startInfo = StartInfo(timestamp: touch.timestamp,
                                   touchLocation: touch.location(in: self),
                                   separatorLocation: separatorView.frame.origin)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first, let startInfo = startInfo {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if moveHorizontally == nil {
            let deltaX = abs(location.x - startInfo.touchLocation.x)
            let deltaY = abs(location.y - startInfo.touchLocation.y)

            if deltaX > 4.0 || deltaY > 4.0 {
                moveHorizontally = deltaX > deltaY
            }
        }

        if let moveHorizontally = moveHorizontally {
            if moveHorizontally {
                print("the user intends to adjust separator position")
                adjustSeparatorViewPosition(usingTouchLocation: location)
            } else {
                print("the user intends to scroll the table view")
                if rightView.frame.contains(location) {
                    rightView.touchesMoved(touches, with: event) // doesn't work
                } else {
                    leftView.touchesMoved(touches, with: event) // doesn't work
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startInfo = nil
    moveHorizontally = nil
    leftView.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    if touch.location(in: self).x < self.bounds.width / 2 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.setSeparatorLocationX(to: self.separatorMinX)
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.setSeparatorLocationX(to: self.separatorMaxX)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startInfo = nil
    moveHorizontally = nil
    leftView.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
}
```

As you can see in this code, I added a delay, just like UIScrollView does when swiping to get the user intention, whether the user want to scroll horizontally or vertically. 
- **If the swipe direction is horizontal**, I want to adjust the separator location
- **If the swipe direction is vertical**, I want to forward the event to the `UITableView` inside it (for example the `leftView`)

But, forwarding the touch event using `rightView.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)` doesn't work.

How to forward the touch event from the `SplitView` to the `UITableView` inside it?

Comment: I would suggest uiswipegesturerecognizer left and right if you can.